# Xml Files In PErvasive Connectors

Tags: java, connector, pervasive

CAn any one p[lase explian me which technology this connection is using, i am unable to find what tags these are

```
<Connection spoketypename="Oracle CRM On Demand" creator="Factory" basename="ServiceDataObjectsDMS" internalname="sdodms" datecreated="20060711T07:43:31Z" connectiontype="Source" connectorproto="" author="Factory" version="1.0" datemodified="20060711T07:43:31Z">
  <Description>
    <![CDATA[Factory created Oracle CRM On Demand through DMS target connection.]]>
  </Description>
  <ResMgrSession name="RMSession1" type="Oracle CRM On Demand"/>
  <ConnectorOptions>
    <Option name="factory" value="Oracle CRM On Demand"/>
  </ConnectorOptions>
</Connection>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those tags are used by the Pervasive Integration tools.  After having contacted Pervasive, I have confirmed these tags are not publicly documented.  A potential user must contact Pervasive (http://www.pervasiveintegration.com).